# Lazy loading in Light Gallery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, lazy-loading, lightgallery

I'm using `lightgallery.js` (https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js) to develop my ASP.NET MVC project.
It seems ok to load some images which have a size of less than 1MB, but the problem here when I use about ~20 pictures (~2MB/picture), Light Gallery will load very slow.
Could you share with me some ideas to overcome this problem?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please check this link http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_basic-usage

Comment: wow, it's easy to combine with lightgallery that I'm looking for.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hi please check this example lazy load image.

For more detail please check the official link -> [Click me](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/#examples)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("ul.jsImageUl > li img").lazy({
        effect: "fadeIn",
        effectTime: 1000
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.lazy/1.7.3/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
<ul class="jsImageUl">
  <li>
     <a href="#"><img data-src="https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3089/2796719087_c3ee89a730_t.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="#"><img data-src="https://farm1.static.flickr.com/143/321464099_a7cfcb95cf_t.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#"><img data-src="https://farm1.static.flickr.com/79/244441862_08ec9b6b49_t.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome, @DuongNguyen :)